# .net core 2.2 multiple bearer token authentication schemes

Tags: .net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, .net-core-2.2

I am currently trying to use 2 different bearer tokens in a .net core 2.2 app. I would like to use an Identity Server token and an Azure AD bearer token. According to Microsoft this is possible (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but I am having no success getting it working.

I have the Identity Server token as the "default" authentication followed by the AzureAD token as documented in the aforementioned link:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = ClockSkew
        };
        o.Audience = Audience;
        o.Authority = IdentityIssuer;
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("AzureAd",o =>
    {
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        };
        o.Audience = AudienceUri;
        o.Authority = Authority
    });
```

Identity Server tokens validate as expected; however Azure AD tokens do not.  They appear to always hit the default Bearer token handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this (I have 2 auth schemes; one for AAD and another one for custom Bearer auth)

```
var url = new MongoUrl(mongoSettings.ConnectionString); // I'm using MONGODB as databse ..but you can choose what you want 

var client = new MongoClient(url);

var database = client.GetDatabase(url.DatabaseName);

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 0;

                // ApplicationUser settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
                //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@.-_";
            }).RegisterMongoStores<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(

p => database.GetCollection<ApplicationUser>("AspNetUsers"),
p => database.GetCollection<ApplicationRole>("AspNetRoles"))
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims

var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appConfiguration.Key));

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                //RequireExpirationTime = true,
                //RequireSignedTokens = true,
                //ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidIssuer = appConfiguration.SiteUrl,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidAudience = appConfiguration.SiteUrl,
                //ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer("AAD", options =>
              {
                  //options.Audience = appConfiguration.SiteUrl;

                  //options.ClaimsIssuer = appConfiguration.SiteUrl;
                  options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                  options.Authority = "https://sts.windows.net/800859e2-e8c3-4842-b31a-3b3727070cb6/v2.0";
                  options.Audience = "5e2ddaf2-2ed3-4829-bbe8-9aa127a754ef";
                  options.SaveToken = true;

                  options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                  {
                      OnMessageReceived = context =>
                      {
                          if ((context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/videohub")
                              //|| context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/looney")
                              //|| context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/usersdm")
                             )
                              && context.Request.Query.TryGetValue("token", out StringValues token)
                          )
                          {
                              context.Token = token;
                          }

                          return Task.CompletedTask;
                      },
                      OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                      {
                          //TODO:
                          return Task.FromResult(0);
                      },
                      OnTokenValidated = context =>
                      {
                          //At this point, the security token has been validated successfully and a ClaimsIdentity has been created
                          var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;

                          //get username
                          var preferred_username = claimsIdentity.Claims.ToList().Where(c => c.Type == "preferred_username").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                          var username = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(preferred_username) ? preferred_username : claimsIdentity.Claims.ToList().Where(c => c.Type == "upn").Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault();

                          //add your custom claims here
                          var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                          var userservice = serviceProvider.GetService<IUsersService>();

                          var us = userservice.Find(xx => xx.UserName == username);
                          if (us == null) return Task.FromResult(0);

                          // ADD SCHEMA (so we know which kind of token is .. from AZURE ACTIVE DIRECTORY .. OR CUSTOM)
                          // TO RETRIEVE THE SCHEMA ..--> //var result = User.Claims.Where(c=>c.Type=="schema").FirstOrDefault().Value;
                          claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("schema", "AAD"));

                          //GET ROLES FROM DB
                          if (us != null && us.Roles.Any())
                          {
                              //add THEM
                              us.Roles.ForEach(rr =>
                               {
                                   claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, rr.ToUpper()));
                               });
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              //OR ADD A DEFAULT ONE
                              claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, Constant.ROLES.Dipendente));
                          }

                          // add MONGDB Id as ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
                          claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, us.Id));

                          return Task.FromResult(0);
                      }
                  };
              }).AddJwtBearer("CUSTOM", options =>
               {
                   //options.Audience = appConfiguration.SiteUrl;

                   //options.ClaimsIssuer = appConfiguration.SiteUrl;

                   options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;

                   options.SaveToken = true;
                   options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                   {

                       OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                       {
                           //TODO:
                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       },
                       OnTokenValidated = context =>
                       {
                           //At this point, the security token has been validated successfully and a ClaimsIdentity has been created
                           var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;

                           //add your custom claims here

                           // ADD SCHEMA (so we know which kind of token is .. from AZURE ACTIVE DIRECOTY .. OR CUSTOM)
                           claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("schema", "CUSTOM"));

                           return Task.FromResult(0);
                       }
                   };
               });
```

then in yours Controller mark class or methid as :

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AAD,CUSTOM")] //<-- yours schema
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
 // ...
}
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: It is a lot easier to use default scheme forward selectors :) You can specify one on the default scheme that checks the token and decides if a different default scheme should be used for the request.

Comment: @juunas what do you mean by that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/policyschemes these :)

Comment: I am currently trying to use the approach suggested by @juunas and decide on the auth scheme to use by looking into the token for a particular claim but it looks like the token is not fully parsed at the point the forward default selector is invoked. The claim collection in `ClaimsPrincipal` is empty.

Comment: you have to fill the claims by your own .. with a service mapped to IAuthorizationHandler ... something like   services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionAuthorizationHandler>(); .. in which you provide the logic to fill the claims for user

Answer (score 0):

Possible things you could try:

1 Set up the default policy

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => { 
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "AzureAD")
           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
           .Build();
```

2 On the OnAuthenticationFailed > under one of the jwtOptions.Events, add a condition if it's authenticated then complete the task and don't show the error. *Sometimes the user is authenticated already but the error from one provider prevents the proper response*

```
 if (arg.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

3 If this doesn't work. There's a hack to check if it's authenticated. Add more conditions per scheme.

```
      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync("AzureAD");
                    if (result?.Principal != null)
                    {
                        context.User = result.Principal;
                    }
                }

                await next.Invoke();
            });
```